# How to get frame form the camera feed in android using Camera2?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-camera2

I'm using Camera2Video implementation from GitHub and trying to get the frames of the camera feed. Below the given code is the EncoderWrapper class from that code. You can check the whole code here : https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2/video

```
package com.example.android.camera2.video

import android.media.MediaCodec
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo
import android.media.MediaFormat
import android.media.MediaMuxer
import android.os.Handler
import android.os.Looper
import android.os.Message
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Surface

import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

class EncoderWrapper(width: Int,
                     height: Int,
                     bitRate: Int,
                     frameRate: Int,
                     orientationHint: Int,
                     mimeType: String,
                     codecProfile: Int,
                     outputFile: File) {
    companion object {
        val TAG = "EncoderWrapper"
        val VERBOSE = false
        val IFRAME_INTERVAL = 1 // sync one frame every second
    }

    private val mOrientationHint = orientationHint

    private val mEncoderThread: EncoderThread by lazy {
        EncoderThread(mEncoder, outputFile, mOrientationHint)
    }

    private val mInputSurface: Surface by lazy {
        mEncoder.createInputSurface()
    }

    private val mEncoder: MediaCodec by lazy {
        MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(mimeType)
    }

    /**
     * Configures encoder
     */
    init {
        val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(mimeType, width, height)

        // Set some properties.  Failing to specify some of these can cause the MediaCodec
        // configure() call to throw an unhelpful exception.
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, bitRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, IFRAME_INTERVAL)

        if (codecProfile != -1) {
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_PROFILE, codecProfile)
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_STANDARD, MediaFormat.COLOR_STANDARD_BT2020)
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_RANGE, MediaFormat.COLOR_RANGE_FULL)
            format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_TRANSFER, getTransferFunction(codecProfile))
            format.setFeatureEnabled(MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.FEATURE_HdrEditing, true)
        }

        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "format: " + format)

        // Create a MediaCodec encoder, and configure it with our format.  Get a Surface
        // we can use for input and wrap it with a class that handles the EGL work.
        mEncoder.configure(format, mInputSurface, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
    }

    private fun getTransferFunction(codecProfile: Int) = when (codecProfile) {
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.HEVCProfileMain10 -> MediaFormat.COLOR_TRANSFER_HLG
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.HEVCProfileMain10HDR10 ->
                MediaFormat.COLOR_TRANSFER_ST2084
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.HEVCProfileMain10HDR10Plus ->
                MediaFormat.COLOR_TRANSFER_ST2084
        else -> MediaFormat.COLOR_TRANSFER_SDR_VIDEO
    }

    /**
     * Returns the encoder's input surface.
     */
    public fun getInputSurface(): Surface {
        return mInputSurface
    }

    public fun start() {
        mEncoder.start()

        // Start the encoder thread last.  That way we're sure it can see all of the state
        // we've initialized.
        mEncoderThread.start()
        mEncoderThread.waitUntilReady()
    }

    /**
     * Shuts down the encoder thread, and releases encoder resources.
     * <p>
     * Does not return until the encoder thread has stopped.
     */
    public fun shutdown() {
        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "releasing encoder objects")

        val handler = mEncoderThread.getHandler()
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(EncoderThread.EncoderHandler.MSG_SHUTDOWN))
        try {
            mEncoderThread.join()
        } catch (ie: InterruptedException ) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Encoder thread join() was interrupted", ie)
        }

        mEncoder.stop()
        mEncoder.release()
    }

    /**
     * Notifies the encoder thread that a new frame is available to the encoder.
     */
    public fun frameAvailable() {
        Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-4")
        val handler = mEncoderThread.getHandler()
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(
                EncoderThread.EncoderHandler.MSG_FRAME_AVAILABLE))
    }

    public fun waitForFirstFrame() {
        Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-5")
        mEncoderThread.waitForFirstFrame()
    }

    /**
     * Object that encapsulates the encoder thread.
     * <p>
     * We want to sleep until there's work to do.  We don't actually know when a new frame
     * arrives at the encoder, because the other thread is sending frames directly to the
     * input surface.  We will see data appear at the decoder output, so we can either use
     * an infinite timeout on dequeueOutputBuffer() or wait() on an object and require the
     * calling app wake us.  It's very useful to have all of the buffer management local to
     * this thread -- avoids synchronization -- so we want to do the file muxing in here.
     * So, it's best to sleep on an object and do something appropriate when awakened.
     * <p>
     * This class does not manage the MediaCodec encoder startup/shutdown.  The encoder
     * should be fully started before the thread is created, and not shut down until this
     * thread has been joined.
     */
    private class EncoderThread(mediaCodec: MediaCodec,
                                outputFile: File,
                                orientationHint: Int): Thread() {
        val mEncoder = mediaCodec
        var mEncodedFormat: MediaFormat? = null
        val mBufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
        val mMuxer = MediaMuxer(outputFile.getPath(), MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)
        val mOrientationHint = orientationHint
        var mVideoTrack: Int = -1

        var mHandler: EncoderHandler? = null
        var mFrameNum: Int = 0

        val mLock: Object = Object()

        @Volatile
        var mReady: Boolean = false

        /**
         * Thread entry point.
         * <p>
         * Prepares the Looper, Handler, and signals anybody watching that we're ready to go.
         */
        public override fun run() {
            Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-6")
            Looper.prepare()
            mHandler = EncoderHandler(this)    // must create on encoder thread
            Log.d(TAG, "encoder thread ready")
            synchronized (mLock) {
                mReady = true
                mLock.notify()    // signal waitUntilReady()
            }

            Looper.loop()

            synchronized (mLock) {
                mReady = false
                mHandler = null
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "looper quit")
        }

        /**
         * Waits until the encoder thread is ready to receive messages.
         * <p>
         * Call from non-encoder thread.
         */
        public fun waitUntilReady() {
            Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-7")
            synchronized (mLock) {
                while (!mReady) {
                    try {
                        mLock.wait()
                    } catch (ie: InterruptedException) { /* not expected */ }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Waits until the encoder has processed a single frame.
         * <p>
         * Call from non-encoder thread.
         */
        public fun waitForFirstFrame() {
            Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-8")
            synchronized (mLock) {
                while (mFrameNum < 1) {
                    try {
                        mLock.wait()
                    } catch (ie: InterruptedException) {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Waited for first frame");
        }

        /**
         * Returns the Handler used to send messages to the encoder thread.
         */
        public fun getHandler(): EncoderHandler {
            synchronized (mLock) {
                // Confirm ready state.
                if (!mReady) {
                    throw RuntimeException("not ready")
                }
            }
            return mHandler!!
        }

        /**
         * Drains all pending output from the encoder, and adds it to the circular buffer.
         */
        public fun drainEncoder(): Boolean {
            val TIMEOUT_USEC: Long = 0     // no timeout -- check for buffers, bail if none
            var encodedFrame = false
            Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-9")
            while (true) {
                var encoderStatus: Int = mEncoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC)
                Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-10")
                if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                    // no output available yet
                    break;
                } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                    // Should happen before receiving buffers, and should only happen once.
                    // The MediaFormat contains the csd-0 and csd-1 keys, which we'll need
                    // for MediaMuxer.  It's unclear what else MediaMuxer might want, so
                    // rather than extract the codec-specific data and reconstruct a new
                    // MediaFormat later, we just grab it here and keep it around.
                    mEncodedFormat = mEncoder.getOutputFormat()
                    Log.d(TAG, "encoder output format changed: " + mEncodedFormat)
                } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " +
                            encoderStatus)
                    // let's ignore it
                } else {
//                    Log.d("Media Format", "${mEncodedFormat?.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_WIDTH)} and ${mEncodedFormat?.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_HEIGHT)}")
                    var encodedData: ByteBuffer? = mEncoder.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus)


                    if (encodedData == null) {
                        throw RuntimeException("encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus +
                                " was null");
                    }

                    if ((mBufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
                        // The codec config data was pulled out when we got the
                        // INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED status.  The MediaMuxer won't accept
                        // a single big blob -- it wants separate csd-0/csd-1 chunks --
                        // so simply saving this off won't work.
                        if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "ignoring BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG")
                        mBufferInfo.size = 0
                    }

                    if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                        // adjust the ByteBuffer values to match BufferInfo (not needed?)
                        encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset)
                        encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size)

                        if (mVideoTrack == -1) {
                            mVideoTrack = mMuxer.addTrack(mEncodedFormat!!)
                            mMuxer.setOrientationHint(mOrientationHint)
                            mMuxer.start()
                            Log.d(TAG, "Started media muxer")
                        }

                        // mEncBuffer.add(encodedData, mBufferInfo.flags,
                        //         mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs)
                        mMuxer.writeSampleData(mVideoTrack, encodedData, mBufferInfo)
                        encodedFrame = true

                        if (VERBOSE) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "sent " + mBufferInfo.size + " bytes to muxer, ts=" +
                                    mBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs)
                        }
                    }

                    mEncoder.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false)

                    if ((mBufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "reached end of stream unexpectedly")
                        break      // out of while
                    }
                }
            }

            return encodedFrame
        }

        /**
         * Drains the encoder output.
         * <p>
         * See notes for {@link EncoderWrapper#frameAvailable()}.
         */
        fun frameAvailable() {
            Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-11")
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "frameAvailable")
            if (drainEncoder()) {
                Log.d("Testing Log", "Log-12")
                synchronized (mLock) {
                    mFrameNum++
                    mLock.notify()
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Tells the Looper to quit.
         */
        fun shutdown() {
            if (VERBOSE) Log.d(TAG, "shutdown")
            Looper.myLooper()!!.quit()
            mMuxer.stop()
            mMuxer.release()
        }

        /**
         * Handler for EncoderThread.  Used for messages sent from the UI thread (or whatever
         * is driving the encoder) to the encoder thread.
         * <p>
         * The object is created on the encoder thread.
         */
        public class EncoderHandler(et: EncoderThread): Handler() {
            companion object {
                val MSG_FRAME_AVAILABLE: Int = 0
                val MSG_SHUTDOWN: Int = 1
            }

            // This shouldn't need to be a weak ref, since we'll go away when the Looper quits,
            // but no real harm in it.
            private val mWeakEncoderThread = WeakReference<EncoderThread>(et)

            // runs on encoder thread
            public override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                val what: Int = msg.what
                if (VERBOSE) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "EncoderHandler: what=" + what)
                }

                val encoderThread: EncoderThread? = mWeakEncoderThread.get()
                if (encoderThread == null) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "EncoderHandler.handleMessage: weak ref is null")
                    return
                }

                when (what) {
                    MSG_FRAME_AVAILABLE -> encoderThread.frameAvailable()
                    MSG_SHUTDOWN -> encoderThread.shutdown()
                    else -> throw RuntimeException("unknown message " + what)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest something on how to get all the frames in the form of a Bitmap from this code? I have tried multiple methods but didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you seen: https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/analyze

Comment: Thanks, @Morrison Chang. I'll give it a try now. Can you suggest something for the above question?